# ES6: how to update a property inside a Class, using getters and methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, es6-class

I want a method to update the value of a property, defined through a getter. 
The property gets the value of an HTML data-attribute, and the method mut just increment it by 1 and update it in the HTML. 
The method is called when a button is clicked. Than the next time the button gets clicked again, I suppose the getter to redefine the value of the property, getting the new value of the data-attribute. But it doesn't occur.

The environment allows me to use jQuery, because the 'element' which is the main argument of the constructor, is a jQuery object representing the HTML target element of the component.

This is the code:

```
import {Components} from 'MyCustomLibrary';

export default class Calendar extends Components{

   get CurrentMonth(){
      return this.element.data('calendar-currentmonth');
   }

   onClickHandler(){
      this.getNewCalendar(this.CurrentMonth);
   }

   getNewCalendar(month){
     /****
     /* jQuery substituted with Vanilla for suggestion in the comments
     $('[data-calendar-currentmonth]').data('calendar-currentmonth',month+1);
     ****/


     let dataAttributes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-calendar-currentmonth]');//.data('calendar-currentmonth',month+1);
     dataAttributes.forEach(function(e){
         e.setAttribute('data-calendar-currentmonth',parseInt(month)+1);
     });
   }

   constructor(element){
       super(element) //element is the html target of component, and it's a jQuery object

       this.element.on('click', this.onClickHandler.bind(this));
   }

}
```

In the html I have my button which is an anchor tag with 'data-calendar-currentmonth=2' attribute. 
Initally it is set to 2, than the first time I click, the function updates the attribute, I can see "3" in my html DOM through console.

But than when I click again, the value of CurrentMonth is again "2", and more, the html doesn't update anymore (maybe just because the property value doesn't update and than 2+1 is always 3).

Isn't getter supposed to be executed every time the property it defines is called? So why does it doesn't get the new value inside the HTML When it is called the second time?

Comment: I suppose `$('[data-calendar-currentmonth'])` should be `this.element`, not some arbitrary selection anywhere in the document?

Comment: `getNewCalendar` should more appropriately be named `setNewCalendar`

Comment: @Bergi It's like this because I need to update every element which has this particular data-attribute. And the first time it does it. It updates all the elements that needs to be updated. And then it doesn't work anymore.... and it's called `getNewCalendar` because more than just updating this parameter it should get the calendar of the new month...

Comment: `$('[data-calendar-currentmonth'])` has the final `']` in the wrong order

Comment: another thing: jQuery does not update the html dom attribute when you modify it with `.data()` method. Try to do a `console.log(this.CurrentMonth);` in onClickHandler

Comment: @LucaRainone unfortunately the problem is not jQuery, I rewrote it with Vanilla and it doesn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found it out that it was jQuery that made the mess. I simply redefined all the variables in Vanilla and it worked perfectly.

I have eliminated the `get CurrentMonth` statement and I have simply passed it directly in the invocation of `getNewCalendar`.

Than my code became like this:

```
 onClickHandler() {
    this.getNewCalendar(this.element[0].getAttribute('data-calendar-currentmonth'));
    /*** 'this.element' is actually a jQuery object. Calling element[0] it comes back to plain js ***/
 }

 getNewCalendar(month) {
    /****
    /* jQuery substituted with Vanilla for suggestion in the comments
    $('[data-calendar-currentmonth]').data('calendar-currentmonth',month+1);
    ****/

    let dataAttributes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-calendar-currentmonth]');//.data('calendar-currentmonth',month+1);
     dataAttributes.forEach(function(e) {
         e.setAttribute('data-calendar-currentmonth', parseInt(month) + 1);
     });
 }

 constructor(element) {
     super(element) // element is the html target of component, and it's a jQuery object

     this.element.on('click', this.onClickHandler.bind(this));
 }
```

Comment: Actually what was wrong was your use of jQuery's `data`. I recommend you read the docs in detail, you shouldn't mix `data` and `attr`/`setAttribute`. `data` reads from the DOM the first time only, after that, it always retreives the value from internal jQuery JS storage. So if you set a new value with `attr`/`setAttribute`, what you get with `data` won't change, you have to set the value with `data(key, value)` to have your changes

Comment: Tahnks @Kaddath got it! The documentation says also «Using the data() method to update data does not affect attributes in the DOM. To set a data-* attribute value, use attr.»! What trapped me was that the first time it seemed to work... so this is now the new question I ask myself: why the first time I clicked the button the data-attribute in the DOM changed?

Comment: It's probably because the data-attribute in the DOM was updated every time, but after the first time it updated with the same value it already had